# Flink: fail fast if job parallelism is larger than the total number of slots

Tags: apache-flink

The [Flink doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/runtime.html) says:

> A Flink cluster needs exactly as many task slots as the highest parallelism used in the job.

But when I run the WordCount example job with job parallelism=4 and 2 slots (2 TM * 1), what I observed was that the Dispatcher still accepted the job and finished some tasks, but a few minutes later this error happened:

```java
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not allocate enough slots within timeout of 300000 ms to run the job. Please make sure that the cluster has enough resources.
```

Is there a way I can configure my job to fail fast if parallelism is larger than the total number of slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flink job manager will try to find resource   across your cluster.

You need to give the Job manager some time, obviously it`s depend on your cluster size and network.

You can change the [slot.request.timeout](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#slot-request-timeout)  in order to get the exception quicker.